# Parse output of mdimport using grep/awk/sed/etc. on macOS?

Tags: macos, awk, sed, grep, zsh

I need to parse the output of mdimport (a Spotlight related tool in macOS)

```
mdimport -t -d3 $file
```

...dumps many attributes and values to stdout, including kMDItemTextContent.

How can I use grep/awk/sed/etc. to leave me with just the value of kMDItemTextContent?

You can use this partial output of mdimport -t -d3 one one of my files as an example.

```
    kMDItemPageHeight = 842;
    kMDItemPageWidth = 595;
    kMDItemPhysicalSize = 12288;
    kMDItemSecurityMethod = None;
    kMDItemTextContent = "11/8 - Hash Tag Test Document #HashTag1 this is the first hash tag. #HashTag2 this is the second hash tag. The following hash tag is inside and at the end of a paragraph: #HashTag3 The next hash tag #HashTag4 is in the middle of a paragraph.";
    kMDItemTitle = "11/8 - Hash Tag Test Document";
    kMDItemVersion = "1.3";
}
```

Note - I have seen explicit \n\n characters within the text block for some of my files.

I guess, my more specific question would be, how can I get all of the text between these two delimiters?

```
kMDItemTextContent = "
```

AND

```
";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple oneline `awk` script:

```
awk -F\" '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}' input.txt
```

Pipe this `awk` script with your command:

```
mdimport -t -d3 $file | awk -F\" '/kMDItemTextContent/{print $2}'
```

Comment: Wow. Perfect. Thank you.